# How to provide Universal Appx Dependencies in Intune Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

I am trying to find how I can upload dependencies using Graph api for Windows Universal AppX type. But nowhere in the documentation it is specified.

Please help me understand or provide pointers, how I can upload a valid appx with dependencies which users can install.

Answer (score 1):

To include dependencies, you upload each dependency as you would upload the main appx file but set the isDependency to true (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata). Please make sure you do not use isFrameworkFile as it will be deprecated.

LeeYan (MSFT)